# What is the minimum length for an answer to be considered hot?

Tags: support, hot-answers

[The "Hot Answers" page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/hot) for a tag says:

> Only top voted, non community-wiki answers of a minimum length are eligible

What is that minimum length?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

300

Comment: Thank you for this definitively un-hot answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know Sam 'Waffles' Saffron was working on this feature a bit.

We were discussing [this query on the data explorer](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/421/interesting-answers-per-tag-in-the-last-n-days).  Although, I'm not sure which numbers he came up with.

Comment: @devin: But this answer is shorter (286 chars) and [is still hot](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/hot/hot?filter=week)!

Comment: I'M SO HOT!!!!!

Comment: @Kenny, well, if you could links and markup, it is over 300.

Comment: @jjnguy: Markup is already counted. Without markup it is 177.

Comment: @Kenny That'd be markdown being counted, actually. Markup would be the resultant HTML tags that are used.

Comment: Oops...Fine...but I'm still hot.